# Ruby SHA1 RSA signing different from command line OpenSSL?

Tags: ruby, openssl, rsa, sha1

I'm trying to implement RSA SHA1 signature verification. 
To my surprise, command line OpenSSL tool doesn't generate the same key as the Ruby OpenSSL.

If I run those commands :

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Geoffrey:ssl_tests Escaflowne$ cat data.txt 
000
MacBook-Pro-de-Geoffrey:ssl_tests Escaflowne$ openssl dgst -sha1 -binary -sign prvkey.pem -out sig.bin data.txt
MacBook-Pro-de-Geoffrey:ssl_tests Escaflowne$ openssl base64 -in sig.bin -out sig64.txt
MacBook-Pro-de-Geoffrey:ssl_tests Escaflowne$ cat sig64.txt
AJEh2kA7O3j624Kdl7UCGN1HiEk/v2LQudB+cjxw1CfmRTjcSPBjUE/EAwy8NEut
K4zYgfRwwTs7NY3AwYiUEtAe5yohUM0Qv17qSDW+G4IWjwe9PKE7Sl00umiMdszA
q/1hqeQlHKgjme7YO7H6i1UcAXmriOOjn+ySRaovsHw=
```

So final base64 result in command line is :
`AJEh2kA7O3j624Kdl7UCGN1HiEk/v2LQudB+cjxw1CfmRTjcSPBjUE/EAwy8NEut
K4zYgfRwwTs7NY3AwYiUEtAe5yohUM0Qv17qSDW+G4IWjwe9PKE7Sl00umiMdszA
q/1hqeQlHKgjme7YO7H6i1UcAXmriOOjn+ySRaovsHw=`

Now, if I try signing it through my ruby script :

```
def sign_message(message)
    privkey = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(Rails.root.join('lib', 'payment', 'prvkey.pem')))

    digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha1')

    expected_sign = privkey.sign(digest, message)
    base_64_expected_sign = [expected_sign].pack('m')

    puts "Expected Signature"
    puts expected_sign
    puts "Base 64 Expected Signature"
    puts base_64_expected_sign

    return base_64_expected_sign
  end
```

And calling the function like this :

```
  def test_sign
    message = "000"
    message_signature = sign_message(message)
    puts "Message Signature : #{message_signature}"

    puts "Valid : #{verify_signature(message_signature, message)}"
  end
```

I get the output :

```
Expected Signature
??|??n?^~?T_1Y@??BR??u???k      x?*????S?L?:.7
                          t??tc?)崪? ?}DMp?p2??4?D-f??jT;!e
                                                              ?k??5??
Base 64 Expected Signature
QjhL1zQoUdGFLVCMg06/CKeE/HdhRTOhJ/p09wkWeK0qD/afsxfcU7tMtDou
Nw3rwXw/5W68XhZ+BK1UXwIxWUDbFYlCUpu6HnWTmI5rC3QP+f50Y8kp5bSq
gQkekH1ETXDmcDKvExeSNKVELWYe3uwTalQ7IWUMyWvnF541rvo=
Message Signature : QjhL1zQoUdGFLVCMg06/CKeE/HdhRTOhJ/p09wkWeK0qD/afsxfcU7tMtDou
Nw3rwXw/5W68XhZ+BK1UXwIxWUDbFYlCUpu6HnWTmI5rC3QP+f50Y8kp5bSq
gQkekH1ETXDmcDKvExeSNKVELWYe3uwTalQ7IWUMyWvnF541rvo=
```

So final ruby OpenSSL signature is :
`QjhL1zQoUdGFLVCMg06/CKeE/HdhRTOhJ/p09wkWeK0qD/afsxfcU7tMtDou
Nw3rwXw/5W68XhZ+BK1UXwIxWUDbFYlCUpu6HnWTmI5rC3QP+f50Y8kp5bSq
gQkekH1ETXDmcDKvExeSNKVELWYe3uwTalQ7IWUMyWvnF541rvo=`

Versus command line :
`AJEh2kA7O3j624Kdl7UCGN1HiEk/v2LQudB+cjxw1CfmRTjcSPBjUE/EAwy8NEut
K4zYgfRwwTs7NY3AwYiUEtAe5yohUM0Qv17qSDW+G4IWjwe9PKE7Sl00umiMdszA
q/1hqeQlHKgjme7YO7H6i1UcAXmriOOjn+ySRaovsHw=`

I've been struggling with this for some time now and I don't understand what could be making a difference!

UPDATE :

Well, apparently results match if I replace my message variable with `File.read(Rails.root.join('lib', 'payment', 'data.txt'))`
So basically, using a string with the same value as what's in the text file doesn't give the same result.
This means it's encoding related right ?

UPDATE 2 :

So the file says its encoded in `us-ascii` if I run `file -I data.txt`
However, if I do `message.encoding.name` it says its loaded as `UTF-8`
Also, `message.encode('ascii')` does not alter the result of the generated signature, it still corresponds with the command line openssl.
As soon as I switch to a string `"000".encode('utf-8')` or `"000".encode('ascii')`, the signatures don't match anymore.
So encoding doesn't seem to play a role at all.

How come there's a difference between the exact same content whether it comes from reading a file or written as a string ?

Comment: I think you just need to use `message = "000\n"` in your Ruby. It looks like you are not taking into account the trailing newline in the file.

Comment: Damn, yes that was it, I thought about it but since I had checked there were no blank characters at the end, I thought it couldn't be that. I guess its added in anyways. Thanks, can you write an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `data.txt` has a trailing newline that you are not taking into account in your code. Using

```
message = "000\n"
```

should work.

You could also do

```
message = File.binread("data.txt")
```

to make sure you get the exact data as the command line.